# Linux Gnome, can NOT install PPAs needed by KIVY

Tags: python, linux, installation, kivy, gnome

The first step on the kivy website already fails:
https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

This fails for bouth repositories, you can choose from
[image: Kivy Install Error]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no PPA for Ubuntu Bionic as shown in the [Kivy PPA list](http://ppa.launchpad.net/kivy-team/kivy/ubuntu/dists/). In the meantime, you might want to [install Kivy in a virtual environment](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#installation-in-a-virtual-environment).